# A Link Img Borders

Tags: css

Is it possible to have a border around an image which is a link via CSS, so that when I hover over the image a border appears around the image? I would like a 5px thick border around every image which is a link, yet I'm not able to get it done quickly :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the content to jump around, you would want to make room for the border when the images are not hovered:

```
a img { padding: 5px; }
```

Then replace the padding with border:

```
a:hover img { padding: 0; border: 5px solid red; }
```

Comment: Or use `outline` instead of `border` which doesn't take up space.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use transparent border, and then set a color: `a img { border: 5px solid transparent; }` and:  `a:hover img { border: 5px solid red; }`.